# Responsive menu similar to Google Plus iOS app

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

In the process of a responsive redesign of a website. For the mobile smartphone view, I'm looking to duplicate the menu that appears in the latest Google Plus iOS app. It consists essentially of a bar w/ 3 icons at the top. If you tab the left icon, the left menu slides out. If you tap the middle icon, a full screen menu drops down to let you choose various options. If you tap the right icon, the right menu slides out. Moreover, you can pull the left and right menus out from the side w/ a slide motion on the screen.

Here's the normal look of the app which shows the menu bar at the top (some details are blurred out).

[image]

Here's the left menu pulled out.

[image]

Here's the middle full screen menu drop down.

[image]

Here's the right menu pulled out from the right.

[image]

What's the best way to duplicate this type of menu design? This will be a responsive design so obviously when viewing on desktop, it will have a different look and behavior.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will not write your code for you. Please try something on your own and come back when you have a specific, answerable problem we can help you with.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to check [sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/), which is a jquery plugin for this specific task only

Its code for creating a left and right menu would be simply something like this

```
<a id="left-menu" href="#left-menu">Left Menu</a> 
<a id="right-menu" href="#right-menu">Right Menu</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#left-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr-left',
      side: 'left' // By default
    });
    $('#right-menu').sidr({
      name: 'sidr-right',
      side: 'right'
    });
});
</script>
```

You can find some sample usages [here](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/#usage)